# Why may "he's real scum" be without any article, while "he's a real hero" must be with the article?

Tags: articles

There are two sentences as an example:

1. If he treats you as good as you say, he's a real hero.
2. If he treats you as badly as you say, he's real scum

[image: two sentences about articles.]

According to the Google Docs, it seems like I must use an article in "he's a real hero". But may not use an article in "he's real scum".

Can you, please, elaborate why? Or it is just a little bug in the application?

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very simply, because **hero** is countable and in most normal situations **scum** is not countable. The following are all similar:

> He's real scum.
> He's real trash.
> He's real soup.
>
> *But*
>
> He's a real hero.
> He's a real prince.
> He's a real idiot.

**Scum, trash,** and **soup** cannot (usually) be counted. **Heroes, princes,** and **idiots** can. Notice that I have used the plural forms in the previous sentence to indicate their countability.

Note that I have used the words *normal* and *usual* a few times. One can always imagine an unusual case in which an uncountable noun can be counted.

Comment: When a non-count noun is used in a count noun sense, it usually refers to types or varieties of the thing. For example, "The two soups on the menu are minestrone and vegetable-beef".